# Parallel processing data queried with EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I use EF6 to fetch data from database. Each item from db needs to be processed. There are heavy calculations and a lot of items and for that reason I want to process them in parallel. I know EF is not thread safe.

The idea is that when the calculator runs it will process the items as they are at that specific run time.

Each item processed needs to be saved back to the db immediately.

So I am thinking about something like:

```
single thread get all items using EF

Parallel.ForEach item in the result query above
   detach the items from main thread context
   create new dbcontext
   attach entities to this thread dbcontext
   calculate
   save all changes
```

Does this sound like a feasible solution keeping in mind entity framework and parallel?

Comment: Fetch data from database and pass theme to a Parallel.ForEach, after finishing the calculation  of each item add the result to a Queue. You have a queue processor method which is in same context of dbcontext that dequeue the items in queue and save the changes in database.

Comment: @MojtabaTajik: makes sense. I believe I have to use a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` right?

Comment: Yes, ConcurrentQueue<T> because your queue used by multiple threads concurrently.

Comment: `var bob = YourData.AsParallel().Select(z => { // Your code here }).ToList();` Doing it this way avoids the need for a `ConcurrentQueue`.